# Symfony Variable "name" does not exist in IbwJobeetBundle:Default:index.html.twig at line 1

Tags: symfony, twig

I am working through the following tutorial: http://www.intelligentbee.com/blog/2013/08/10/symfony2-jobeet-day-4-the-controller-and-the-view/

I am on Day 4 setting up the templates:

When loading the page I get a error: Variable "name" does not exist in IbwJobeetBundle:Default:index.html.twig at line 1

looking through the debug information that is generated it I see that it is a getTemplateName function that is throwing the error.

Here is what is in the index.html.twig file the first line is extending the layout.html.twig that is located in the view directory could someone give me an Idea of why it may not be finding the file

```
{% extends 'IbwJobeetBundle::layout.html.twig' %}
```

{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}
    
{% endblock %}

Comment: How do you render the template in your controller ? It looks like you're trying to use a variable that does not exist in one of your templates. `[edit]` By the way, the error probably comes from layout.html.twig

Comment: Thanks for the quick response I was rendering the wrong template in  the controller changed that and it is working. Thanks